# GcmTaskService not working

Tags: java, android

Привет, хочу заменить в своем проекте BroadcastReceiver на GcmNetworkManager. Посмотрел некоторые статьи и сделал по примеру:
1) В манифест добавил:

```
<service android:name=".WakeOnLanService"
      android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.BIND_NETWORK_TASK_SERVICE"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

2) Service:

```
public class WakeOnLanService extends GcmTaskService {

@Override
public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {
    return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_SUCCESS;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int i, int i1) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Выполнилось",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, i, i1);
}
}
```

3) Добавил в activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GcmNetworkManager mGcmNetworkManager = GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(this);
    Task task = new OneoffTask.Builder()
            .setService(WakeOnLanService.class)
            .setExecutionWindow(0, 2)
            .setTag("MyTag")
            .setUpdateCurrent(true)
            .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .build();
    mGcmNetworkManager.schedule(task);
}
}
```

Но почему то такой подход не работает. Подскажите, может я что то не так сделал или не доделал? И как правильно сделать что бы сервис запускался при появлении интернета?

Comment: Может быть у Вас все работает, а просто нет доступа к экрану. Попробуйте заменить Toast(...) на Log.d(TAG, "Выполнилось")

Comment: Да пробовал, не работает